# Reduce Number of calls to repository pattern with data filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to implement an API which gets data from a repository and saves data to the same repo.
API has these methods which I have to implement:

- GetHospitals()
- GetHospital(int hospitalId)
- CreatePatient(Patient patient)

IRepository Code:

```
public interface IRepository
    {
        ICollection<Hospital> GetHospitals(Func<Hospital, bool> filter);
        ICollection<Patient> GetPatients(int storeId);
        Patient AddPatient(Patient patient);
    }

public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public int HospitalId { get; set; }        
}
 public class Hospital
{
    public int HospitalId { get; set; }
    public string HospitalCode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

My issues are that

1. it is asking me to make minimum calls to IRepository(basically 1 call) and then use the data to carry operations. How do I achieve this ?
2. Secondly I am not able to understand the Func<T,T> which is required for GetHospitals.
3. Third, there will be a call made on this API which will have hospitalcode sent. IF code is sent, then request filtered data else get all data.

I am working on below code.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
 private ICollection<Hospital> _hospitals = null;
 public ApiController(IRepository repository)
  {
  _repository = repository;
  _hospitals = _repository.GetHospitals(x => x.HospitalCode != null); //temporary request
  //_hospitals = _repository.GetHospitals(/*how to request data here*/);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am confused about your questions. (i) What you exactly want from *minimum calls to IRepository(basically 1 call) *  (ii) Are you want implement IRepository interface ? (iii) Why there are not API endpoints in your controller?

Comment: @BinRohan so if i try to use _repository.FunctionName() more than once in any of the methods i get test case error of IRepository should be called only once. I do not have to implement IRepository

Comment: @BinRohan any way how to filter data through the Func<> method input ?

Comment: why are u making repository call in constructor?

Comment: @VireshMathad the api methods can be called in any way. so to initialise the _stores , i am trying to do so else it will have to be populated only via GetStores() , so if _stores is empty and I try to access GetStore(), it will result in error as _stores is empty. Should i not be doing it ?

Comment: its better call them in their relevant actions rather than in ctor. I usually use DI to get instance of object and call functions in the controller action